# adding transparent/watermarked text over another layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing a simple application with one main layout.  The application has a state which users can toggle.  If the state is "on", I want see-through (watermarked, although I know this can have a different meaning) text to overlay the main layout.  I am guessing I would have to define a second layout to lay over the main layout.  Or maybe not.  If I'm not totally crazy, I would appreciate any guidance.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, xml allows you to put UI elements in order you want, just put last one the TextView with text you want to have as overlay.

Comment: I want the transparent text to be on top other elements in the layout

Comment: Well, still do not understand what the problem is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textColor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should'nt need to create another layout. Just put a TextView in your main layout and use this to change its transparency

```
int alpha = 100;
mTxt.setTextColor(Color.argb(alpha, 0, 0, 0));
```

alpha can be anything 0-255, 0 being transparent and 255 being 100% solid. You can also change the `0,0,0` to a different RGB value if you don't want black text.

You can also set the alpha from xml if you want (Which you should do unless you need to change it at run time):

```
<TextView
...
...
android:background="#55000000" />
```

in this instance the first two digits represent the alpha value (55 in the example), they can be between 00 and FF. The next 6 digits are the RGB value in hex.

Comment: How do I get the TextView to be on top of other UI elements?  Stacked, so to speak.

Comment: If you are using Relativelayout, you can easily position the textView on top of another view. Just see to it that the views are positioned in the manner that they will overlap.

Comment: Good, I will check out this layout.  Thanks!